# Providing two authentication mechanisms within same spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-security

Here is what I am trying to do:
A GET request to http://localhost:8080/token is authenticated using Google OAuth2 (Authorization code flow). If authenticated, a custom JWT token is returned as a response.

All other urls (such as /hello1, /hello2, hello3 etc.) are authenticated using JWT token that is present in the Authorization header. This is the same token that was given out by the /token end point.

I am able to get both of these authentication mechanisms working separately but it is not working when I combine both of them using the following configuration.

I have two WebSecurityConfigs as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityInfoOAuth2 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http
        .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/token", "/oauth/**", "/oauth2/**")
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/oauth/**", "/oauth2/**").permitAll()
         .anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
         .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
         .and()
         .oauth2Login()
                .userInfoEndpoint()
                    .userService(oauthUserService)
                .and()
                .successHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
                    ...NOT SHOWN...
                });
    }
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityInfoJWT extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/hello1", "/hello2", "/hello3")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Now, the /token endpoint is working fine. It returns a token.

But here are the two issues that I am seeing:

1. It is redirecting me to OAuth2 social login for all URLs (even for the ones that are not present in the config) although I expect it to do so only for /token
2. Even with the Authorization header present, the request to /hello1 is redirecting to social login. I have put in a break point in jwtRequestFilter, but the control is not even going there.

How do I make sure WebSecurityInfoJWT configuration is used for /hello1 ?

Comment: Why do you want to combine both? OAuth 2 can provide an access token to pass as a bearer header and also supports another authentication type like username/password (password grant type). In this way, you have the same security mechanism for all the API endpoints.

Comment: Because I need /hello1 to be authenticated using a custom token and /token to be authenticated using OAuth2. I don't want /hello1 to be authenticated using OAuth2 and /token to be authenticated using custom token (even if such a token is present in the request).

Comment: Why -1? The question is quite clear. I need two different authentication mechanisms for two different urls.

Comment: Can you try to put the /hello1 to the permitAll() in WebSecurityInfoOAuth2 because it seems it is filtered by OAuth2 and this is the reason of the redirection.

Comment: That didn't work. In fact, I commented out everything in WebSecurityConfigOAuth2. Now , it is just:
public class WebSecurityConfigOAuth2{ }
and it is still redirecting everything to oauth2.

Could it be because of the following config in application.yml?

security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
         google:  
...

Comment: I removed security props from app.yml and now everything is getting redirected to /login Where did that come from?